# Linq: are there alternative way to filter on a property inside a List inside a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq

I don't like to have the where condition inside the select, but I couldn't find a better solution. I also thought of using SelectMany as a first step to get all the BookTemplate objects from all the List x Dictionary. Any suggestion?

```
public class BookTemplate    {public string EventCategory { get; set; }}
public string eventCategory;
public Dictionary<int, List<BookTemplate>> IDProgramNodeBookTemplatesMap { get; set; }
int[] idsArray = new[] {sportId, categoryId, tournamentId, eventId};

List<IEnumerable<BookTemplate>> tmp = (from tuple in IDProgramNodeBookTemplatesMap
    join id in idsArray on tuple.Key equals id
    select tuple.Value.Where(t => t.EventCategory == eventCategory)).ToList();
```

I've tried that it was wrong, the correct solution was the following. Is it efficient?

```
List<BookTemplate> tmp = (from tuple in IDProgramNodeBookTemplatesMap
                join id in idsArray on tuple.Key equals id
                from evt in tuple.Value
                where evt.EventCategory == eventCategory
                select evt).ToList();
```

Comment: Well, what is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: There is room for improvement, but what you have is actually rather nice. A few things that you could improve: 1. place the `where` clause prior to the `join` clause; 2. replace the `join` clause with `where idsArray.contains(tuple.Key)`; 3, make the ids a `HashSet<int>`; 4 just call it `ids`

Comment: @AluanHaddad: thanks! Answer if you like so I can accept it

Comment: @Revious, I don't feel like it's really an SO Q/A, more of a code review since your code already worked. Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: you are probably right, thanks!